# Terminology help for a set relation: for sets $X, Y$, not necessarily disjoint, such that neither is a subset of the other.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

Is there an existing term for pairs of sets $X, Y$, not necessarily disjoint, such that neither $X \subseteq Y$ nor $Y \subseteq X$?

Would it be incorrect (or misleading) to call them something like "incongruent" sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply "*$\subseteq$-incomparable*" should suffice.

Incongruent would bring connotations of some sort of congruency relation, but this is not the case, since $\subseteq$ is not a congruence relation. It's just a partial order.