# How do you call a non-empty intersection of two sets, where none of the sets is a subset of the other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Consider two sets $A$, $B$ with the following properties:

- $A \cap B\not = \emptyset$
- $A \not \subseteq B$
- $A \not \supseteq B$

Describing the relation of $A$ and $B$, the terms "disjoint", "subset" and "superset" can only be used along with "not". Is there a precise name for this scenario? I only can think of "non-empty intersection which corresponds to neither of the original sets", which is not really helpful when it comes to coding, for example.

The following question is related, but also includes the disjoint case: [Terminology help for a set relation: for sets $X, Y$, not necessarily disjoint, such that neither is a subset of the other.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362174/terminology-help-for-a-set-relation-for-sets-x-y-not-necessarily-disjoint?rq=1)

Comment: incomparable intersecting sets? intersecting can be replaced by non-disjoint (but more indirect though).

Comment: No, there is no fancy name for this scenario.

Comment: How does 'overlapping' or 'intersecting' sound ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @TomCollinge 'overlapping' also applies to the $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ cases. We have actually been using it for everything which is not disjoint in our project.

Comment: Partially overlapping?

Comment: @paw88789 I could go with that. Still wonder if someone pops up with an "official term".

Comment: nondisjoint and incomparable